# Text running off page for cventry in moderncv

Tags: formatting, margins, moderncv

I'm redoing my CV with the [moderncv](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/moderncv-banking) template and it's mostly working quite well (though I admit I'm playing fast and loose with the intended purpose of certain fields to fit an academic profile). However, there's a formatting issue with my teaching section because the name of some classes are quite long:

[image]

As you can see, the field with the date can only start *after* the field with the course title on the line above, which pushes it into the margin. How can this be fixed so that the date aligns properly with the right margin?

Here (I hope) is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{black}      
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\name{Firstname}{Lastname}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Baskerville}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\cventry{Autumn 2015}{Postgraduate Tutor (History Department, University of York)}{The Hundred Years War}{}{}{}

\cventry{Spring--Summer 2015}{Postgraduate Tutor (History Department, University of York)}{From Rome to the Renaissance: The Transformation of Traditional Societies, c. 400--1650}{}{}{}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I put the too-long text in a left-aligned (`[l]`) and borderless **box with a width of 0 mm**:
>   `\makebox[0mm][l]{From Rome...}` that occupies no horizontal space.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{black}      
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

% Added
\usepackage{showframe}

\name{Firstname}{Lastname}

% Removed
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Baskerville}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\cventry{Autumn 2015}{Postgraduate Tutor (History Department, University of York)}{The Hundred Years War}{}{}{}

\cventry{Spring--Summer 2015}{Postgraduate Tutor (History Department, University of York)}{From Rome to the Renaissance: The Transformation of Traditional Societies, c. 400--1650}{}{}{}

\cventry{Spring--Summer 2015}{Postgraduate Tutor (History Department, University of York)}{\makebox[0mm][l]{From Rome to the Renaissance: The Transformation of Traditional Societies, c. 400--1650}}{}{}{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Magnificent, that's cleaned it right up, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Class `moderncv` has a fixed definition of command `\cventry`, for example for style `banking`

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular*}{\maincolumnwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}% <============
    {\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5}\\%
    {\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}} & {\itshape #2}\\%
  \end{tabular*}%
  \ifx&#7&%
  \else{\\%
    \begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}%
      \small#7%
    \end{minipage}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```

with the resulting command in the cv:

```
\cventry[length--1]{year--year--2}{Degree--3}{Institution--4}{City--5}{\textit{Grade}--6}{Description--7}  % arguments 4 to 7 can be left empty
```

The main part of the command is set in a tabular, only the last part is a minipage, which can contain more than one line without problems.

So you can change your command to:

```
\cventry{Spring--Summer 2015}%
  {Postgraduate Tutor (History Department, University of York)}%
  {}%
  {}{}%
  {From Rome to the Renaissance: The Transformation of Traditional Societies, c. 400--1650}
```

With the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{black}      
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\name{Firstname}{Lastname}

%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Baskerville}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\cventry{Autumn 2015}%
  {Postgraduate Tutor (History Department, University of York)}%
  {The Hundred Years War}%
  {}{}{}

\cventry{Spring--Summer 2015}%
  {Postgraduate Tutor (History Department, University of York)}%
  {From Rome to the Renaissance: The Transformation of Traditional Societies, c. 400--1650}%
  {}{}{}

\cventry{2}%
  {3}%
  {4}%
  {5}{6}{7}

\cventry{Spring--Summer 2015}%
  {Postgraduate Tutor (History Department, University of York)}%
  {}%
  {}{}%
  {From Rome to the Renaissance: The Transformation of Traditional Societies, c. 400--1650}

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image]

Just adding `\makebox[0mm][l]` is not working, because there should be a line break that can not be added.  See this with a litte bit longer text:

```
\cventry{Spring--Summer 2015}%
  {Postgraduate Tutor (History Department, University of York)}%
  {\makebox[0mm][l]{From Rome to the Renaissance: The Transformation of 
    Traditional Societies, c. 400--1650, some text, to make this sentence 
    a little bit longer}}%
  {}{}{}
```

Then you get the result:

[image]

As you can see the bold shorter text is already too long, no more space for argument 5 ...

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to keep the course name rather than my title in the prominent spot because that's really the bit that matters, but thanks for the explanation of why it has the issue in the first place--it's nice to understand what's going on!